# Setting Label in iPhone's Lock screen Playback Controls

Tags: ios

When using AVAudioSession, how can I set the label in the lock screen playback controls to the title of the audio clip I am currently playing? Basically, I want the label to look the same as the iPod app's locks creen playback controls where it shows the song name. Currently, my app shows the app name in the label I want changed.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 5 you can use following code:

```
Class playingInfoCenter = NSClassFromString(@"MPNowPlayingInfoCenter");

if (playingInfoCenter) {
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *center = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];
    NSDictionary *songInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"Some artist", MPMediaItemPropertyArtist,
                              @"Some title", MPMediaItemPropertyTitle,
                              @"Some Album", MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle,
                              nil];
    center.nowPlayingInfo = songInfo;
}
```